# where does Visual web part and webpart get deployed in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can anyone let me help in knowing the storage location of sharepoint custom webpart deployed as sandbox.

I know that a farm solution gets deployed to Layout folder in sharepoint but where does sandbox solution gets deployed I mean does content DB has any role in it?

Comment: but in sharepoint 2013 farm soln dnt get deployed in layout folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your sandboxed web part gets serialized and placed into the content database, as with any artifact deployed as a sandbox solution.